# When is end of while?

Tags: c++, while-loop

There is a code that I can't understand if there is any part of the code that causes exiting of the loop without exiting the whole program.

Here is the code:

```
/* per-packet event loop */
while (true)
{
  perf_push (PERF_EVENT_LOOP);

  /* wait on tun/socket list */
  multi_get_timeout (&multi, &multi.top.c2.timeval);
  status = multi_tcp_wait (&multi.top, multi.mtcp);
  MULTI_CHECK_SIG (&multi);

  /* check on status of coarse timers */
  multi_process_per_second_timers (&multi);

  /* timeout? */
  if (status > 0)
  {
    /* process the I/O which triggered select */
    multi_tcp_process_io (&multi);
    MULTI_CHECK_SIG (&multi);
  }
  else if (status == 0)
  {
    multi_tcp_action (&multi, NULL, TA_TIMEOUT, false);
  }

  perf_pop ();
}
  /* shut down management interface */
 uninit_management_callback_multi (&multi);
```

Is the last line reachable?

Comment: Did you try to indent inner blocks of code with matching parentheses at some indention?

Comment: What did your try to understand? Debug?

Comment: I see `while (true)` and not a single `break` or `return` statement...

Comment: @Mare Infinitus: I want to understand the code in order to improve the performance of the code...

Comment: @Mysticial: Me too! but after this while, there is some codes... I can't figure out why...

Comment: Are any of those function calls macros in disguise? A `break` in a macro would be the only way this can break out.

Comment: @Mysticial: hmm... Thanks for the reply, this is a good idea; I must check it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the definition of the macro `MULTI_CHECK_SIG`. I googled for `MULTI_CHECK_SIG` and found a definition in terms of another macro `EVENT_LOOP_CHECK_SIGNAL` which contained a `break` statement.

Comment: ha, I was thinking exactly same - there must be 'break' inside MULTI_CHECK_SIG as it looks like macro. Macros are most often written in capitals by many software develepors.

Answer (score 1):

The loop looks like it has no ending. This is often the case in embedded systems programming. The loop is then simply ended by disconnecting the power supply. Hardware cannot stop working, so there will always be a loop that has no ending condition.
In Linux (and other operating systems) you could also terminate the program by implementing IPC signal functions.